# Probability of 5 of 6 different independent events

Tags: probability

I would like to know how I would figure out the probability of exactly 5 of 6 independent events resulting in success when each of those events have a different probability for success:

P(1)= 56% 
P(2) = 78%
P(3)= 85%
P(4)=75%
P(5)=95%
P(6)=65%

How would I go about figuring out the probability of exactly 5 of those 6 events succeeding?

Comment: There are six mutually exclusive cases, where "exactly 5 of those 6 events" occur.  Multiply and add.  Since the probabilities are different, but independent, there isn't a lot you can do to avoid the work.

Answer (score 0):

We consider all possible successful outcomes. Let $Q(x)$ be a probability function of $x,$ where $1 \leq x \leq 6,$ and $x$ is an integer. Define $Q(x)$ to be the product of $P(k)$ of all $k$ other than $x.$ Then our answer can be written as $$\sum_{x = 1}^{6}{(1 - P(x)) \cdot Q(x)}.$$